# How do I add a listener to the Android toolbar in MAUI?

Tags: android, maui

I need to intercept taps on the Android back arrow/hamburger icon.
In Xamarin, getting the toolbar and adding a method to toolbar.NavigationClick was rather easy inside a NavigationPageRenderer:

```
protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
    var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null)
    {
        toolbar.NavigationClick += Toolbar_NavigationClick;
    }
}
```

Now I need to find a way to do it in MAUI since the NavigationPageRenderer has been deprecated. I don't want to use obsolete code in a brand new MAUI app.
In MAUI.iOS, there is a NavigationRenderer that sets up pretty much like it does in Xamarin.iOS, but I've been unsuccessful in figuring it out in Android.

I have tried getting the toolbar in a PageHandler and in a NavigationViewHandler, but the toolbar is always null:

```
// this is in my NavigationViewHandler
protected override View CreatePlatformView()
{
    var vw = base.CreatePlatformView();
    var toolbar1 = vw.FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    var toolbar2 = vw.FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Layout.Toolbar);
    // both of thosw return null
    return viewGroup;
}
```

I think my main challenge is I don't understand how to work these handlers, and we all know how well Microsoft documents things, so it's time to ask all you folks who are smarter than me. Maybe there's a more simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Xamarin Forms app, I used the following to access the Toolbar :-

```
    public void SetToolbar()
    {
        // This was used previously when targeting older versions of Android
        //var toolBar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

        var toolBar = FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

        SetSupportActionBar(toolBar);
    }
```

This then allowed the OnOptionsItemSelected method to be overridden to do some processing based on the back arrow being pressed :-

```
    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        var result = base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);

        PerformBack();

        return result;
    }
```

In .NET MAUI, I have been able to locate the Toolbar using the following :-

```
public void SetToolbar()
{
    var linearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.navigationlayout_appbar);

    if (linearLayout != null)
    {
        var child1 = linearLayout.GetChildAt(0);

        if (child1 is MaterialToolbar child1AsMaterialToolbar)
        {
            SetSupportActionBar(child1AsMaterialToolbar);
        }
    }
}
```

This then allows the same OnOptionsItemSelected method to be overridden :-

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    var result = base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);

    PerformBack();

    base.OnBackPressed();

    return result;
}
```

You will notice a call to base.OnBackPressed(), this is because the back navigation is, unfortunately broken using this approach.

This is far from an ideal solution due to :-

1. The use of the obsolete base.OnBackPressed method to ensure the back navigation still works
2. I also found that you need to make sure the SetToolbar method is called after the page your navigating to is fully rendered otherwise the OnOptionsItemSelected won't get fired